# Ошибка при удалении из друзей

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При удалении пользователя из друзей выдает ошибку:

> `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in `FriendshipsController#destroy`
>   Couldn't find `Friendship` with `'id'=2` [`WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ?`]

Контроллер `friendships`:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:success] = "Пользователь добавлен в друзья."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Невозможно добавить в друзья."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Пользователь удален из друзей."
    redirect_to current_user
  end

end
```

Контроллер `users`:

```
def my_friends
  @friendships = current_user.friends
end
```

Файл презентации в контроллере `users`:

```
<% @friendships.each do |friend| %>
    <%= friend.name %>
      <%= link_to "Профиль пользователя", user_path(friend), class: "button" %>
      <%= link_to "Удалить из друзей", friendship_path(friend), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Связи между моделями приведите.

Comment: User:  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => 'Friendship', 
                                 :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

Comment: Friendship: belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из представленного кода это непонятно, но я так понимаю что в модели `User` что-то типа

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships, class_name: "User"
```

Если это так, то проблема вот в чём:

> ```
> @friendships = current_user.friends
> ```

Но

> ```
> def destroy
>   @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
>   # ...
> end
> ```

Т.е. форма отправляет идентификатор друга(пользователя), а контроллер ждёт идентификатор "дружбы" (промежуточной таблички).
Самым простым вариантом, наверное, будет такой:

```
def destroy
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by(friend_id: params[:id])
  #...
end
```